# How to change language in Facebook login page?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, facebook

In Facebook API, there is a [Hackbook project](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook) for a demo.

When I try to login to facebook via this Hackbook project, the login page is always not in English.

URL of the login page is http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?xxxxxxx  (it has more parametors .... )

so, I visited Facebook site(www.facebook.com) in Safari and changed the language to English, but the language in the login page from Hackbook project is not changed.

How can I change it to English? or is there the auto language detection in Facebook?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There is an autodetection based on safari. I've tried to force the language on http://m.facebook.com adding the parameter "?locale2=en_EN"

So if you access to http://m.facebook.com/?locale2=en_EN, facebook login will be in english, but if you change the locale you can load any language you want (example: http://m.facebook.com/?locale2=es_ES for spanish)

I pressume you can use this parameter in your dialog call, but I didn't tried yet.

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

Don't work with `en_EN`, but with `en_US` worked. Also we can use `locale` param instead of `locale2`