# How to specify the language to be used in the Facebook Login Dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, localization, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Javascript SDK for facebook to login a user with Facebook:

Documentation FB.Login: [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

Unfortunatly this dialog is always in English.

FB.Dialog will trigger a popup window with url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?PARAMETERS
```

With the help of another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557509/how-to-change-language-in-facebook-login-page) here I found that I can add locale2 parameter:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?PARAMETERS&locale2=es_ES
```

With this extra parameter the dialog is now shown in Spanish.

But I can't find how to pass this language paramter to the FB.Login function so it's also used in the login dialog.

Is there any function known that can help me with this issue?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/internationalization#:~:text=Note%20that%20this%20only%20applies%20to%20plugins%20and%20buttons%20that%20are%20directly%20integrated%20with%20your%20site.%20Dialog%20such%20as%20the%20Login%20Dialog%20render%20in%20the%20language%20that%20the%20person%20has%20picked%20as%20their%20native%20language%20on%20Facebook%2C%20even%20if%20it%27s%20different%20than%20the%20language%20you%20select.  

so does not matter what param locale you will pass it is goign to use language provided in user setting profile

Comment: Now with the version v16, there seems to be no place to change the locale now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be something to do with the SDK source you are using

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

```
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
```

Change **en_US** to your language locale **es_ES** and that might fix it.

Comment: Aha, right. I was looking at the wrong place for this. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 2):

You can set locale while loading Facebook SDK:

```
   // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
```

As you can see, in link assigned to `js.src` there is `en_GB` part. If you want to load SDK with current user's locale, you can check the locale before loading SDK and then use this here.